# Create a separate chaining hash table contain words derived from a txt file

Tags: c++, string, hashtable

I want to create a separate chaining hash table containing words derived from a txt file (for example : a dictionary) in which each word lies in a line. I got an error that my program could insert words into a hash table. Can you give advice about where the problem is in my code I am a novice and my English is not good, Sorry for this inconvenience?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int PRIME_CONST = 7;
class HashMapTable
{
    int table_size{};
    //Pointer to an array containing the keys
    list<string>* table;
public:
    // constructor and methods
    HashMapTable(int ts);
    int hashFunc(string key)
    {
        int hashCode = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
        {
            hashCode += key[i] * pow(PRIME_CONST, i);
        }
        return hashCode % table_size;
    }
    void insertElement(string key);
    void deleteElement(string key);
    void show(string key);
    void display();
};

HashMapTable::HashMapTable(int ts)
{
    table_size = ts;
    table = new list<string>[table_size];
}

void HashMapTable::insertElement(string key)
{
    int hash = hashFunc(key);
    table[hash].push_back(key);
}

void HashMapTable::display()
{
    list<string>::iterator j;
    for (int i = 0; i < table_size; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
        for (j = table[i].begin(); j != table[i].end(); j++)
            cout << *j << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    HashMapTable ht(26);
    string x;
    fstream draft;
    draft.open("draft.txt", ios::in);
    if (draft.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(draft, x))
        {
            //Here x seems not to be inserted into ht, because display() function show nothing
            //But when I substituted x by a specific string like "hello", it works
            ht.insertElement(x);
        }
    }
    draft.close();
    ht.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post a proper [mcve]. it saves everyone time from having to ask "clarifying" questions, such as: by what magic is the apparently-stand-alone `hashFunc` acquiring its mysterious `table_size` value, as it seems completely disjoint from `HashMapTable`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your hash function.

For long strings there will be an integer overflow soon and the resulting hash_value will be negative.

Additionally, it may be possible, that the source file with the data is not where you expect it to be. I added an error message for such a case.

I slightly modified your code and added an even more efficient hash function. Then everything will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int PRIME_CONST = 7;
class HashMapTable
{
    int table_size{};
    //Pointer to an array containing the keys
    list<string>* table;
public:
    // constructor and methods
    HashMapTable(int ts);
    unsigned int hashFunc(string& key)
    {
        unsigned hash = 0;
        for (const char c : key) hash = hash * 101 + c;
        return hash % table_size;
    }
    void insertElement(string key);
    void deleteElement(string key);
    void show(string key);
    void display();
};

HashMapTable::HashMapTable(int ts)
{
    table_size = ts;
    table = new list<string>[table_size];
}

void HashMapTable::insertElement(string key)
{
    int hash = hashFunc(key);
    table[hash].push_back(key);
}

void HashMapTable::display()
{
    list<string>::iterator j;
    for (int i = 0; i < table_size; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
        for (j = table[i].begin(); j != table[i].end(); j++)
            cout << *j << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    HashMapTable ht(26);
    string x;
    fstream draft;
    draft.open("draft.txt", ios::in);
    if (draft.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(draft, x))
        {
            //Here x seems not to be inserted into ht, because display() function show nothing
            //But when I substituted x by a specific string like "hello", it works
            ht.insertElement(x);
        }
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "\nError: Could not open source file\n";
    draft.close();
    ht.display();
    return 0;
}
```